# Mysql get user value following user task

Tags: mysql

i have a table named (Barcode) as follow

| id | USER_CODE |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A1-123 |
| 2 | A2-456 |
| 3 | A3-123 |
| 4 | A4-789 |

i tried separate user from user_code by :

```
select *,
        substring_index(`barcode`.`user_code,'-',1) AS `user_name` 
from barcode
```

it gives result as follow :

| id | USER_CODE | user_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A1-123 | A1 |
| 2 | A2-456 | A2 |
| 3 | A3-123 | A3 |
| 4 | A4-789 | A4 |

now :

how can i set table to be like

| code | A1 | A2 | A3 | A4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | DONE |  | DONE |  |
| 456 |  | DONE |  |  |
| 789 |  |  |  | DONE |

any hint would be appreciated ,thank u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try using pivoting logic here:

```sql
SELECT
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(user_code, '-', -1) AS code,
    IF(SUM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(user_code, '-', 1) = 'A1') > 0, 'DONE', '') AS A1,
    IF(SUM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(user_code, '-', 1) = 'A2') > 0, 'DONE', '') AS A2,
    IF(SUM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(user_code, '-', 1) = 'A3') > 0, 'DONE', '') AS A3,
    IF(SUM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(user_code, '-', 1) = 'A4') > 0, 'DONE', '') AS A4
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(user_code, '-', -1);
```

### Demo